# Three.JS - material not loading on object

Tags: javascript, three.js

I use Blender in combination with the exporters from Three.js
and spit it out in JSON. I like to apply a texture on a object but it seems not to work.  What am I doing wrong?

```
var feinleinenMap = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('textures/feinleinen.jpg');
feinleinenMap.anisotropy = 16;
feinleinenMap.wrapS = feinleinenMap.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
feinleinenMap.repeat.set(5, 5);



var feinleinen = {

    "schwarz": new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0x222222,
        map: feinleinenMap,
        combine: THREE.MixOperation
    }),
        "weiss": new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0xffffff,
        map: feinleinenMap,
        combine: THREE.MixOperation
    }),
        "chamois": new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0xEDE6D4,
        map: feinleinenMap,
        combine: THREE.MixOperation
    }),
}

var group = new THREE.Group();


loader.load('/models/dagobert/basis.js', function (geometry) {
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, feinleinen["schwarz"]);
    loadJson(mesh);
});

function loadJson(mesh) {
    group.add(mesh);
}

scene.add(group);
```

Comment: what are you getting. errors on the console? (PS. you dont need a server)

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your scene through a server, else the texture wont load.

http://www.wampserver.com/en/ PC

https://www.mamp.info/en/ mac

Or use Brackets live preview and it should work for you.

Comment: localhost should be fine, or not?